# How to escape apostrophe from a string in power automate

Tags: power-automate, powerapps

I have an array of people names which also contact a name of a person who has apostrophe in their name and I need to encode those names how should I do it?

I have tried replacing the single quote with double quote but that is not possible in my case as I have an array of names which needs to be encoded in the further step.

Comment: Normally you don't need to. Where are the names coming from? And encoded for what? Update your question with more detail.

Comment: Two single quotes I’m pretty sure. Show us the flow though.

Comment: Can you show us how you have configured the flow and how you are using the user names with apostrophe in flow actions?